# Trying to get random cursor from collection - Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to publish a random question from a collection of questions. However I get an error stating: Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors.  How do I change my publication below so this outputs one random question?

Publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('randomQuestions', function(){
var randomInRange = function(min, max) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return random;
};
var q = Questions.find().fetch();
var count = q.length;
var i = randomInRange(0, count);
return q[i]
});
```

Router.js

```
this.route('gamePage', {
 path: '/games',
 waitOn: function() {
     return [
         Meteor.subscribe('randomQuestions'),
     ];
 }
});
```

Here is a helper on the client side to get the random question

```
Template.gamePage.helpers({
    displayRandomQuestion:
        function() {
            return Questions.find({});
        }
});
```

Lastly here is the html/css using the helper function

```
<div class="questions">
    {{#each displayRandomQuestion}}
      {{> questionItem}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a cursor for a single random question.

```
Meteor.publish('randomQuestion', function (seed) {
  var q = _.sample(Questions.find().fetch());
  return Questions.find({_id: q && q._id});
});
```

You should also subscribe using a random seed to ensure that clients don't share the same publication. The below example requires that you `meteor add random`.

```
this.route('gamePage', {
 path: '/games',
 waitOn: function() {
   return Meteor.subscribe('randomQuestion', Random.id());
 }
});
```

You can then return that one question in a helper

```
Template.gamePage.question = function() {
  return Questions.findOne();
};
```

and provide that data as the context for your template.

```
<div class="question">
  {{> questionItem question}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is a kiddie pool question, but why did you use q && q._id instead of just q._id?

Comment: If `q` is undefined (which can happen for reactive data fetched from Minimongo), then using `q._id` will throw an exception. `q && q._id` yields to the same result and is safe.