# Angular - Meteor: Publish returns full data set instead of parameterised set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

So I have a MongoDB collection in my Angular-Meteor project and I want to return a subset of the collection (one item in specific) using the find or the `findOne` methods.

Here's a look at that:

```
Meteor.publish('eventById', function(eventId){
  console.log("The eventId you received is as follows:");
  console.log(eventId);
  return Events.find({ _id: eventId });
});
```

The eventId I get is correct (looks like yFzEuDfeLAweiWTEd). However when I console log the actual returned value I have the full array with all data blocks in them. I only need the one based on the Id though.

My controller code looks as follows:

```
var self = this;
  self.currentEventId = $stateParams.id;
  self.currentEvent = $scope.$meteorCollection(Events, false).subscribe('eventById', self.currentEventId);

  console.log(self.currentEventId);
  console.log(self.currentEvent);
```

Logging `self.currentEvent` gives me the same array as I would get from a regular `Events.find()` call.

The schema for an event is the following:

```
{
"title": "Meteor Power Lunch",
"description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sem nisl, mattis nec odio at, dignissim pharetra elit. Aliquam non ante enim. Praesent quis convallis.",
"date": "04/05/2016",
"imageUrl": "/images/bizz-party.jpg",
"bannerUrl": ""
}
```

What I'm expecting to get is a single one of these objects whereas Events is a Mongo collection of these events. I'm passing in the generated ID for these items through the url (http://localhost:3000/event/XZGgPvLdf4Kfx5fmr) in this manner.

Comment: What's wrong with using the `findOne()` method?

Comment: the 'findOne()" method doesn't return the right data either. Could you perhaps give me an example of what that method should look like if i wanted to find by id?

Comment: Could help but would need some salient details like what your `Event` collection schema looks like, some sample data and the output you are anticipating. Can you then use the [edit] link to include in your question those details?

Comment: I edited my question. Hope you have what you need :)

Comment: That returns the following error: 
`Exception from sub eventById id XceGk8QHJ7cdwtJ8Y Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors`

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702110/ the answer in that question should help.

Comment: I'm afraid that post doesn't help me at all, I've tried it before but the two seem rather unrelated.

Comment: As the error explicitly states, the publish function can only return a cursor and since `findOne()` does not return a Mongo cursor but a Mongo document, just leave `return Events.find({ _id: eventId });` as is since that will return a single document cursor which is what the publish call expects. You can then access the single document via the array index as `console.log(self.currentEvent[0]);`

Comment: As it turns out, when I look for an item by ID using what you just described, it doesn't affect the order of the items in my array. That means that looking for `self.currentEvent[0]` will always be the same item regardless of my parameter.

Comment: Might be worth checking this doc as it says the meteorCollections feature will be removed in the next api release http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/meteorCollection